# В чём причина ошибки "request for member '...' in something not a structure or union"?

Tags: c, указатели, структуры

Код такой:

```
struct {
    int number;
    char symbol;
} something[5];

something[0].number = 28;
int *pointer = &something[0];

printf("%i", pointer -> number);
```

Последняя строка вызывает ошибку `request for member 'number' in something not a structure or union`.

Пробовал `(*pointer).number` - та же ошибка. В чём может быть её причина?

Comment: `int *pointer = &something[0];` - это уже бессмыслица. Не игнорируйте сообщения компилятора.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Причина ошибки в том, что `pointer` — это указатель на `int`, а не на структуру.

Правильным бы было дать структуре некое имя, а не оставлять её анонимной:

```
struct myStruct {
    int number;
    char symbol;
} something[5];

struct myStruct *pointer = &something[0];
```